# Make code with differentiation by cases work for arrays and numbers

Tags: python, numpy

I often find myself writing code that is supposed to work for single numbers and `numpy` arrays. If that code needs a differentiation by cases, I either use some weird constructions like adding multiples of `numpy.sign` or similar, or I find myself writing blocks like

```
    try:
        lon[x<0] -= pi
    except IndexError:
        if x<0:
            lon -= pi
```

Is there an easy idiomatic way to write statements like `lon[x<0] -= pi` so they work for both numbers and arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If speed is not an issue, you can do:

```
lon -= (x<0)*pi
```

which always gives you the right answer, but in the case of arrays, there's more subtraction (by 0) done than needed.

Comment: I mostly don't care about speed, but sometimes I have multiplications in these constructions, and `y *= (x<0)*2` does of course do something entirely different :-)

Comment: for multiplication, you can do `y *= 2 ** (X < 0)`

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `numpy.where` which supports both arrays and scalars:

```
lon -= np.where(x<0, pi, 0.)
```